# Understanding the IF formula within a SUMIFS formula

Tags: excel-formula

I'm completing an edx course on data analysis in excel. In one of the tasks you have to create a summary table using the the following formula:

```
=SUMIFS(SalesTable[Revenue], 
SalesTable[Product Category],$K7, 
SalesTable[Year],Q$6, 
SalesTable[Country],IF($C$1="(All)","*",$C$1), 
SalesTable[Customer Gender],IF($C$2="(All)","*",$C$2), 
SalesTable[Age Group],IF($C$3="(All)","*",$C$3))
```

I'm trying to understand what the "*" does in the IF formulas which form the criteria for the SUMIFS formula. The IF formulas are linked to filters connected to my summary table i.e. the summary table will filter for country, customer gender, and age group depending on the selected filter in C1, C2 and C3 (similar to pivot table). I've checked the discussion forums on the web page and nothing appears to provide an explanation.

Any help would be great,

Thanks

Comment: It is a wildcard that will pick up everything.

Comment: Cool, so for example with the SalesTable[Country] the IF formula is basically saying: from the column country if (All) is selected sum all the values for SalesTable[Revenue], if not sum all the values for whichever country is selected in $C$2

Comment: That's correct for logic, but $C$1, $C$2 is for gender. @AndrewAC